# 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: java, windows, path, javac

I am using java 12.0.2, `JAVA_HOME` is set as `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2` and `PATH` is having `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`
still when I try executing `java` command its giving me the error `'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

`java` and `javac` are part of `JRE` and `JDK 12` doesn't have `JRE` now, so how to setup this.
please don't relate this issue with old questions, until java8 it's fine but its not working now in windows 10.
[image: this is the JAVA_HOME]

[image: this is the Path entry]

[image: command prompt still showing error]

[image: path screenshot]

Comment: When you get that error message, it means that the executable that you're trying to run (in this case 'JAVA') was not found.

Comment: This is a question about windows `PATH` management, not Java.  I would first check that `java` is in `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` and then that this is really in the `PATH` that is in effect where you are trying to run it.  We need more details about the environment you're having problems with.

Comment: Try restarting your command line window or any application where you want to use the newly set PATH variables.

Comment: @Dropout I have restarted the PC as well still the issue persists.

Comment: @asm please see the screenshots i have added.

Comment: Reopening the issue.

Comment: @krishnathota can you also show `echo %PATH%` in that command prompt?

Comment: @asm added the screenshot of echo, please review.

Comment: @krishnathota Can you copy that out of your path, add `\java` at the end, and see if you can run that at the command prompt?

Comment: @asm I have tried reaching to `bin` directory and ran `java` command, though it is available its still showing the same message. even as Admin I tried.

Comment: @krishnathota Are you sure that specific directory actually exists?

Comment: It might just be a matter of needing to close CMD, reopen CMD, and check again.

Answer (score 2):

> java and javac are part of JRE and JDK 12 doesn't have JRE now, so how
> to setup this.

After JDK 10, there is no separate JRE shipped and you do not need a separate JRE anymore. The JDK is enough.

> I am using java 12.0.2, JAVA_HOME is set as C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2 and PATH is having %JAVA_HOME%\bin

The space in the path may cause problems. I suggest you set `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2\bin` directly into `PATH`. Also, make sure to promote this entry to the top (beginning) so that this entry overrides the existing Java version (if any).

Last but not the least, start a new **cmd** window session to check `java -version` because the changes in the environment variables using the GUI does not become effective in already open **cmd** windows.

For any misconfiguration, if you can not make it work, [download a fresh JDK and follow the instructions on the download page](https://adoptopenjdk.net/installation.html#x64_win-jdk).

Comment: I have added the bin folder to path explicitly as well but no luck.

Comment: @krishnathota - Select this entry and keep clicking the button, `Move Up` until it becomes the first entry. If it does not solve your problem, simply install JDK 12 again. During a fresh installation, I suggest you override the suggested path with a custom path without space.

Comment: I tried re-installing as well, no luck. however Intellij is able to work perfectly fine.

Comment: @krishnathota - Make sure you are installing the right version e.g. if you install 32-bit version, probably that won't work.

Comment: `jdk-12.0.2_windows-x64_bin` its a 64bit one only I tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing any existing java paths and making sure your JAVA_HOME is correct. There is no JRE but the java command should work if your env vars are correct. It is most likely a configuration error so deleting old configuration and reconfiguring will probably hlep.

Comment: I just reinstalled the OS and added the env variables for java.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by Python which was not allowing to execute java/javac commands. Once I uninstall the python everything worked fine.

I am still not sure what happened when I install Python as I explicitly didn't do anything except enabling the tick mark to setup the path variable while installing it.